# How to simplify this regex to avoid recursion?

Tags: php, regex

Regex:

```
(?|`(?>[^`\\]|\\.|``)*`|'(?>[^'\\]|\\.|'')*'|"(?>[^"\\]|\\.|"")*"|(\?{1,2})|(:{1,2})([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*))
```

Example input:

```
INSERT INTO xyz WHERE 
a=? 
and b="what?"
and ??="cheese"
and `col?`='OK'
and ::col='another'
and last!=:least
```

https://regex101.com/r/HnTVXx/6

It should match `?`, `??`, `:xyz` and `::xyz` but not if they are inside of a backquoted-string, double-quoted string, or single-quoted string.

When I try running this in PHP with a very large input I get `PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR` from `preg_last_error()`.

How can I simplify this regex pattern so that it doesn't do so much recursion?

---

Here's some test code that shows the error in PHP using [Niet's optimized regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43145826/65387): https://3v4l.org/GdtmP Error code 6 is `PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR`. The other one I've seen is 3=`PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR`

Comment: @anubhava: No, it will match a `?` in `and b="wha\"t?"`

Comment: OP regex [handles escaped quotes](https://regex101.com/r/3CuYWG/1).

Comment: @JakubSzumiato Har har... I'd have to parse the entire SQL query in PHP if I didn't use a regex. (Which I've actually attempted, but the existing libs fail on a bunch of edge cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea to skip quoted parts (the `(*SKIP)(*F)` combo), but also 2 techniques to reduce the regex engine work:

- the first character discrimination
- the unrolled pattern

These 2 techniques have something in common: limiting the cost of alternations.

The first character discrimination is useful when your pattern starts with an alternation. The problem with an alternation at the beginning is that each branch should be tested so that a position where the pattern fails is identified. Since most of the time, there are many failing positions in a string, discarding them quickly constitutes a significant improvement.

For instance, something like: `` "...|'...|`...|:... `` can also be written like this:

```
(?=["'`:])(?:"...|'...|`...|:...)
```

or

```
["'`:](?:(?<=")...|(?<=')...|(?<=`)...|(?<=:)...)
```

This way, each position that doesn't start with one of these characters `` ["'`:] `` is immediately rejected with the first token without to test each branch.

---

The unrolled pattern consists to rewrite something like: `" (?:[^"\\]|\\.)* "` into:

```
" [^"\\]* (?: \\. [^"\\]* )* "
```

Note that this design eliminates the alternation and reduces the number of steps drastically:
[basic](https://regex101.com/r/g02tK6/2)
[unrolled](https://regex101.com/r/g02tK6/1)

---

Using these 2 techniques, your pattern can be written like this:

```
~
[`'"?:]
(?:
    (?<=`) [^`\\]*+ (?s:\\.[^`\\]*|``[^`\\]*)*+ ` (*SKIP) (*F)
  |
    (?<=') [^'\\]*+ (?s:\\.[^'\\]*|''[^'\\]*)*+ ' (*SKIP) (*F)
  |
    (?<=") [^"\\]*+ (?s:\\.[^"\\]*|""[^"\\]*)*+ " (*SKIP) (*F)
  |
    (?<=\?) \??
  |
    (?<=:) :? ([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)
)
~x
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/kt7uFn/1)

---

Other way: instead of using an alternation (improved or not) at the beginning, you can build a pattern that matches all the string with contiguous results. The general design is:

```
\G (all I don't want) (*SKIP) \K (what I am looking for)
```

`\G` is an anchor that matches either the position after the previous result or the start of the string. Starting a pattern with it ensures that all the matches are contiguous. In this situation (at the beginning of the pattern and in factor to the whole pattern), you can also replace it with the A modifier.

That gives:

```
~
[^`'"?:]*
(?:
    ` [^`\\]*+ (?s:\\.[^`\\]*|``[^`\\]*)*+ ` [^`'"?:]*
  |
    ' [^'\\]*+ (?s:\\.[^'\\]*|''[^'\\]*)*+ ' [^`'"?:]*
  |
    " [^"\\]*+ (?s:\\.[^"\\]*|""[^"\\]*)*+ " [^`'"?:]*
)*
\K  # only the part of the match after this position is returned
(*SKIP) # if the next subpattern fails, the contiguity is broken at this position
(?:
    \?{1,2}
  |
    :{1,2} ([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)
)
~Ax
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWRTgk/1)

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to work that in too. Should work fine with the quote backreference like Niet did too, right? That makes the regex a bit cleaner.

Comment: @mpen: the quote backreference is a false good idea. If it makes the pattern shorter, it also increases the number of steps. And if you use it, you can't use the unrolled subpattern technique.

Comment: I guess I'll have to transfer the checkmark to you then -- looks like yours is more efficient! About half the number of steps according to regex101. Learned a lot today, thank you.

Comment: Did some tests on it -- I don't hit any recursion limits now. I run out of memory before getting a stack overflow :D

Comment: @mpen: I will add an other approach based on contiguity.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea of "match this thing, but not in this condition" can be achieved with this pattern:

```
(don't match this(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|match this)
```

In your case, you'd want something like...

```
(
  (['"`]) # capture this quote character
  (?:\\.|(?!\1).)*+ # any escaped character, or
                    # any character that isn't the captured one
  \1      # the captured quote again
  (*SKIP)(*FAIL)   # ignore this
  |
  \?\??   # one or two question marks
  |
  ::?\w+  # word characters marked with one or two colons
)x
```

https://regex101.com/r/HnTVXx/7

Comment: [No it doesn't match `?` in `b="wha\"t?"`](https://regex101.com/r/HnTVXx/4)

Comment: That's pretty sweet. I didn't know about `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. I think I'm still hitting PHP's limits though. I'll post some code in a second.

Comment: Here: https://3v4l.org/GdtmP The subject might just be too big though -- your regex looks pretty efficient (thank you!)

Comment: @mpen I've made a teeny-tiny adjustment: `*+` instead of just `*` near the top. This now works in PHP7 but for some reason (not sure why) PHP5 still fails with a backtrack limit error. It could well be that your input is too long for PHP5, but PHP7 had some change that allows it to work with the possessive `*+` quantifier.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That teeny change buys me an extra 200K characters in PHP 5.6 too, which is great! It craps out somewhere at about 330K byte input. That'll have to do. Thank you so much!